# Error in Call Option Valuation using Implicit Finite Difference implemented in Python

Tags: black-scholes, programming, finite-difference-method

I am trying to valuate call option using implicit Finite difference method (Forward Marching) implemented in Python. However I am getting the error in the code. Following is the code I have developed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Set max row, columns to 200
pd.set_option('max_rows', 200)

pd.set_option('max_columns', 200)

#specify the parameters
#time to maturity
T = 1

#strike price
K = 100

#riskfree rate
r = .05

#volatility
vol = .20

#Flag = 1 for call, -1 for puts
Flag = 1

#number of steps
steps = 20

#asset step size
ds = 2* K / steps

#time step size for stability
dt = (0.9/vol**2/steps**2)

#time steps
time_steps = int(T / dt) + 1

#time step size
dt = T / time_steps

#Create asset steps i*ds
s = np.arange(0,(steps+1)*ds,ds)

#Create time steps k*dt
t = T-np.arange(time_steps*dt,-dt,-dt)

grid = np.zeros((len(s),len(t)))

#Subsume the grid points into a dataframe with asset price as index and time steps as columns
grid = pd.DataFrame(grid, index=s, columns=t)
print(grid)

#Set Final or Initial condition at Expiration
if Flag == 1:
    grid.iloc[:,0] = np.maximum(s - K, 0)
else:
    grid.iloc[:,0] = np.maximum(K - s, 0)

def implicitFiniteDifference_ForwardMarching(K, Volatility, Rate, TTM, steps, Flag=1):
    # Specify Flag as 1 for calls and -1 for puts

    ds = 2*K/steps                   # asset step size
    dt = 0.9/Volatility**2/steps**2  # for stability

    time_steps = int(TTM / dt) + 1          # time step size 
    dt = TTM/time_steps                     # time step

    s = np.arange(0,(steps+1)*ds,ds)
    t = TTM-np.arange(time_steps*dt,-dt,-dt)

    # Initialize the grid with zeros
    grid = np.zeros((len(s),len(t)))
    grid = pd.DataFrame(grid, index=s, columns=t)

    # Set boundary condition at Expiration
    grid.iloc[:,0] = np.maximum(Flag * (s - K), 0)

    for k in range(1, len(t)):
        for i in range(1,len(s)-1):
            delta = (grid.iloc[i+1,k+1] - grid.iloc[i-1,k+1]) / (2*ds)
            gamma = (grid.iloc[i+1,k+1]-2*grid.iloc[i,k+1]+grid.iloc[i-1,k+1]) / (ds**2)
            theta = (-0.5* vol**2 * s[i]**2 * gamma) - (r*s[i]*delta) + (r*grid.iloc[i,k-1])
            grid.iloc[i,k] = grid.iloc[i,k-1] - dt*theta

        # Set boundary condition at S = 0 and S = infinity
        grid.iloc[0,k] = grid.iloc[0,k-1] * (1-r*dt)
        grid.iloc[len(s)-1,k] = abs(2*(grid.iloc[len(s)-2,k]) - grid.iloc[len(s)-3,k])

    # round grid values to 4 decimal places
    return np.around(grid,4)

#Call the function for pricing call
fdmcall = implicitFiniteDifference_ForwardMarching(100,0.2,0.05,1,40,Flag=1)

print(fdmcall)
```

Error starts like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9af6f8d89957> in <module>()
     90 
     91 #Call the function for pricing call
---> 92 fdmcall = implicitFiniteDifference_ForwardMarching(100,0.2,0.05,1,40,Flag=1)
     93 
     94 print(fdmcall)

<ipython-input-4-9af6f8d89957> in implicitFiniteDifference_ForwardMarching(K, Volatility, Rate, TTM, steps, Flag)
     77     for k in range(1, len(t)):
     78         for i in range(1,len(s)-1):
---> 79             delta = (grid.iloc[i+1,k+1] - grid.iloc[i-1,k+1]) / (2*ds)
     80             gamma = (grid.iloc[i+1,k+1]-2*grid.iloc[i,k+1]+grid.iloc[i-1,k+1]) / (ds**2)
     81             theta = (-0.5* vol**2 * s[i]**2 * gamma) - (r*s[i]*delta) + (r*grid.iloc[i,k-1])
```

then lots of computer-specific stack trace, then:

````
   2137         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   2138         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 2139             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```
````

Comment: The proximate cause is that on the last loop through `for k in range(1, len(t))`, `k`=72, and you're calling `.iloc[.., k+1]`, which blows up because the grid is not long enough. If you change the loop to `for k in range(1, len(t)-1):` it will run to completion, but I can't speak to whether that fixes your pricing problem.

Comment: Again thanks StackG!! Works wonders!!. The grid values are correct!!